# MySQL: Can Tables Be Locked Recursively?

Tags: mysql, recursion, locking, nested

Can MySQL (InnoDB) tables be locked **recursively**?

Can't find any mention of nesting or recursion in the LOCK TABLES documentation.

The default behavior seems to be (based on what I've observed) that the second lock implicitly UNlocks the first lock.

Is there any way to make it function recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by **recursively**, you mean calling `LOCK TABLES` repeatedly, creating a series of nested locks, then the answer is "no". Calling `LOCK TABLES` on a table implicitly releases any current locks held on that table by that thread.

From [the MySQL LOCK TABLES syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html):

> `UNLOCK TABLES` explicitly releases any table locks held by the current session. `LOCK TABLES` implicitly releases any table locks held by the current session before acquiring new locks.

Comment: Ya, that's the behavior I've been observing so far.

Is there any way to **make it** function recursively?

Comment: @AJ.DE why do you need to? Sounds more like you want a transaction.

Comment: There isn't a way to recursively lock in MySQL.

Comment: We have a database API layer that has several functions which can either be called directly or indirectly by other api functions.  each function should lock its total group of database calls, which creates a natural lock recursion in the case where 1 calls another.

Comment: I guess I'll just do the recursion in the API layer.